# CA based Tomcat client authentication

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, keystore, ca

I have troubles setting up a mutual authentication scheme using **Tomcat 7** in **Centos 7**.
The server authentication is working as expected, but I am stuck on the client authentication.

The server certificate and the clients certificates are issued by the same CA. My goal is to allow any client with a certificate issued by this CA.

So far, my server.xml looks like this for the concerned connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150"
               scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" SSLEnabled="true"
               keystoreFile="/absolute/path/to/mykeystore.jks" keystorePass="P455W0RD" keyAlias="myalias" 
               clientAuth="true"        
               truststoreFile="/absolute/path/to/mykeystore.jks" truststorePass="P455W0RD"
/>
```

When the keystore contains the client certificate, the mutual authentication successes. 
However, when the keystore contains only the CA, the mutual authentication fails.

I have generated my keystore with the commands below:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in  server.crt -inkey server.key -out server.p12 -name myalias -CAfile ca.crt -caname root
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass <pass> -destkeypass <pass> -destkeystore mykeystore.jks -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass <pass> -alias myalias
keytool -importcert -alias root -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass <pass> -file ca.crt
```

I also tried to remove the truststoreFile and truststorePass parameters from the connector, and add the CA to the cacerts in **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/**, but the mutual authentication still fails.

Could you please indicate me how to set up such a mutual authentication configuration?